# Change fragments from spinner drop down items?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-fragmentactivity

My activity has a spinner and an empty container where fragments should be added when selecting drop down items from spinner.

My plan was to try to make switch construction inside into override method "public void onItemSelected()", where each case represents one drop down item from spinner, and sets correct fragment into container, like this:

```
String itemSelectedFromSpinner = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
switch (itemSelectedFromSpinner) {
            case "first item":  // First and second item put same fragment into container, but do other methods when used
            case "second item": // my code
        }
```

My other taught was to put it in if construction like this:

```
String itemSelectedFromSpinner = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (itemSelectedFromSpinner.equals("first item") || itemSelectedFromSpinner.equals("second item")){
    // my code }
```

Since I've never done something like this, and I believe you can understand from my question what needs to be done, tell me what is the best practice to do that.

Am I doing it right by putting a String itemSelectedFromSpinner into switch construction? Also if user selects one item and first fragment is loaded, when selecting other item will the first fragment disappear and put second fragment into container automatically? (sorry if this sound little silly to you, I have lack of experience with fragments)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use string like `"first item"` in code directly - move them to string resources.
2. For components like spinner use [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html). The concept of Adapters use widely in Android so it's a good idea to be familiar with it. And also it allow you to compare your data by some integer asigned id's, and not by strings (which is unefficient, slow and ugly - correcting string representation everywhere is hard).
3. To replace or add Fragments dynamically use [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html). See the simple `replace() / add() / commit()` code